# Why we add $2\pi k$ when taking a root

Tags: complex-analysis

When taking a root, let say $r=\sqrt[n]{w}$ we look at $w$ as $pe^{(\theta+2\pi k) i}$

But in this case we have repetition so we take $k=0,1,...,n-1$ we not just take  $w=pe^{\theta i}$?

Comment: When you handle with roots of complex numbers, you have to take a look at Riemann surfaces. There are exactly n roots of a complex number! Please note that $e^{2\pi i}=1$ and so $e^{2\pi i k}=1$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the process of taking the $n$'th root of $pe^{(\theta + 2k\pi)i}$, we calculate the exponent as $(\theta + 2k\pi)i/n$, which, for different values of $k$, really does give different complex numbers.

Example: The number $i$ may be written as $1\cdot e^{(\pi /2)i}$. Thus $\sqrt[2]i = \sqrt[2]1\cdot e^{(\pi/4) i}$. However, $i$ can *also* be written as $1\cdot e^{(\pi/2 + 2\pi)i}$, and using that, we get $\sqrt[2]i = \sqrt[2]1\cdot e^{(\pi/4+\pi)i}$, which is not the same.

Comment: So in the first place why not to determine that we take numbers without multiplies of $2\pi$?

Comment: @newhere That's called "making a branch cut", and it's entirely valid and common. More specifically, it's common to require all angles to be either in the interval $[0, 2\pi)$ or $(-\pi, \pi]$ or something like that, exactly so that things like roots are uniquely valued. However, you lose some niceness as well, specifically continuity: If you have a point moving about the complex plane, and you follow along its $n$'th root, then with the branch cut the $n$th root will make jumps. Without the branch cut the $n$th root will move continuously. Both approaches have their strengths.